# xmlunit: strange matching for pom.xml files

Tags: java, maven, matching, xmlunit

I am trying to get the differences of two Maven POM files with the XMLUnit. First of all my code:

```
package com.company.control.cfgmgnt.tools.pommerge.core.internal.xml.comparison;


import java.io.File; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DetailedDiff;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Difference;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.DifferenceConstants;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLTestCase;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit;  
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.examples.RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier;

import com.company.control.cfgmgnt.tools.pommerge.core.internal.xml.DocumentReader;


public class ComparisonTask extends XMLTestCase
{

public List<Difference> testAllDifferences( final File f1, final File f2, final boolean includeComments )
        throws Exception {
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments( !includeComments );
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace( true );

    String myControlXML = DocumentReader.readXMLfile2String( f1 );
    String myTestXML = DocumentReader.readXMLfile2String( f2 );

    DetailedDiff myDiff = new DetailedDiff( compareXML( myControlXML, myTestXML ) );
    myDiff.overrideElementQualifier( new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier() );
    List<Difference> _out = cleanDifferenceOutput( myDiff.getAllDifferences() );
    return _out;
}

private static List<Difference> cleanDifferenceOutput( final List<Difference> list ) {
    ArrayList<Difference> out = new ArrayList<Difference>();
    for ( Difference dif : list ) {
        if ( ( dif.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND_ID )
                || ( dif.getId() == DifferenceConstants.TEXT_VALUE_ID ) ) {
            out.add( dif );
        }
    }
    return out;

}

}
```

Here the control POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>phoenix-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.phoenix</groupId>
    <version>1.24.0-control-java7-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.company.control.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-control-java7-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<developers>
    <developer>
        <!-- user id of the responsible person (used for email) -->
        <id>xyyyyy</id>
        <!-- display name of responsible person -->
        <name>xxxxx yyyyy</name>
        <roles>
            <role>projectmanager</role>
        </roles>
        <properties>
            <!-- end date of this project, it will be automatically removed afterwards -->
            <estimatedProjectEndDate>2014/01/08</estimatedProjectEndDate>
        </properties>
    </developer>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.company.com/phoenix/svn/phoenix/projects/feature/control-java7/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.company.com/phoenix/svn/phoenix/projects/feature/control-java7/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url><![CDATA[http://svn.company.com/phoenix/svn/phoenix/projects/feature/control-java7/]]></url>
</scm>
<issueManagement>
    <system>JIRA</system>
    <url>http://jira.company.com/browse/TFWK</url>
</issueManagement>
```

... and the test POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>1.24.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>./parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<groupId>com.company.control.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>1.1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>project aggregator for project.stabletrunk</description>
<issueManagement>
    <system>JIRA</system>
    <url>http://jira.company.com/browse/</url>
</issueManagement>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>maven-sites</id>
        <name>repository for Maven Websites</name>
        <url>scp://phoenix-sites.company.com/maven-sites/projects/stableTrunk/${project.version}/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<properties>
    <sonar.branch>${project.artifactId}</sonar.branch>
    <sonar.host.url>http://phoenix-sonar.company.com</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
```

When I print out the XPath of the differences this are the control/test pairs I get:

```
/project[1]/parent[1]/artifactId[1]/text()[1]
/project[1]/parent[1]/artifactId[1]/text()[1]

/project[1]/parent[1]/groupId[1]/text()[1]
/project[1]/parent[1]/groupId[1]/text()[1]

/project[1]/parent[1]/version[1]/text()[1]
/project[1]/parent[1]/version[1]/text()[1]

null
/project[1]/parent[1]/relativePath[1]

/project[1]/version[1]/text()[1]
/project[1]/version[1]/text()[1]

/project[1]/developers[1]/developer[1]/id[1]
null

/project[1]/developers[1]/developer[1]/name[1]
null

/project[1]/developers[1]/developer[1]/roles[1]
null

/project[1]/developers[1]/developer[1]/properties[1]
null

/project[1]/scm[1]/connection[1]/text()[1]
/project[1]/issueManagement[1]/system[1]/text()[1]

/project[1]/scm[1]/developerConnection[1]/text()[1]
/project[1]/issueManagement[1]/url[1]/text()[1]

/project[1]/scm[1]/url[1]
null

null
/project[1]/distributionManagement[1]/site[1]/id[1]/text()[1]

null
/project[1]/distributionManagement[1]/site[1]/name[1]

null
/project[1]/distributionManagement[1]/site[1]/url[1]

/project[1]/issueManagement[1]/url[1]
null

null
/project[1]/properties[1]
```

And now my question: Why does the element "issueManagement" not match? It is in both POMs...

Answer (score 0):

`<url>http://jira.company.com/browse/</url>`

is not the same as

`<url>http://jira.company.com/browse/TFWK</url>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure it is not the same, but    <system>JIRA</system> is. On the other hand <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.company.com/phoenix/svn/phoenix/projects/feature/control-java7/trunk</connection>
 and <system>JIRA</system>
are clearly not the same...

Comment: Ok, I have written my own Qualifier. Now it works as I wanted.